# How can I unregister an event from another scene or another script?

Tags: unity, c#

This is where and how I register the event :

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (Time.timeScale == 0)
            {
                DisableEnableUiTexts(true);
                SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(0);
                if (fadeImage != null)
                    fadeImage.SetActive(true);
                GetGameMusicVolume();
                Cursor.visible = false;
                Time.timeScale = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame = false;
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded;
                Cursor.visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the event :

```
private void SceneManager_sceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
    {
    }
```

I need to be able to unregister the event either from another scene or another script.

Comment: We'll need more details about what script is registering this event in Update, and why. Have you considered unregistering the event after you handle it, ie. in SceneManager_sceneLoaded itself?

Comment: @DMGregory You right. In the end I just unregister the event in the bottom of the event it self.

Comment: Want to share that as an Answer then?

Comment: I will share it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to unregister the event in the end of the event it self :

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (Time.timeScale == 0)
            {
                DisableEnableUiTexts(true);
                SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(0);
                if (fadeImage != null)
                    fadeImage.SetActive(true);
                GetGameMusicVolume();
                Cursor.visible = false;
                Time.timeScale = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame = false;
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded;
                Cursor.visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SceneManager_sceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
    {
        fadeImage = GameObject.FindWithTag("Game Scene Fader");
        if (fadeImage != null)
            fadeImage.SetActive(false);
        audioMixer.SetFloat("gamemusicvolume", Mathf.Log(0.0001f) * 20);
        DisableEnableUiTexts(false);
        var pauseResumeMainMenuMode = FindInActiveObjectByName("MenuDefaultButtons_Canvas_Pause_Resume");
        var newFreshGameMainMenuMode = FindInActiveObjectByName("MenuDefaultButtons_Canvas_NewFreshGame_SaveGame_Not_Exist");

        newFreshGameMainMenuMode.SetActive(false);
        pauseResumeMainMenuMode.SetActive(true);

        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= SceneManager_sceneLoaded;
    }
```

In the Update registering :

```
SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded;
```

In the bottom of the event unregistering :

```
SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= SceneManager_sceneLoaded;
```